# mysqli affected rows returning 0 with an array of items

Tags: php, mysqli

I came across the following problem.
I have an array of items that I want to update. Below is my code:

```
public function addTranslation( $data = array(), $language ) {
    // Add all words to language
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE `languages` SET `$language` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $translation, $id);

    $count = 0;
    foreach( $data as $id => $translation ) {
        $stmt->execute();

        if( !empty( $translation ) ) {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    // Check if all filled in words are added
    echo $stmt->affected_rows;
    if( $stmt->affected_rows >= $count ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know that the query works fine because when I checked my database after the script ran the updated values are there. Also `$stmt->affected_rows` works in other places. The problem I have is that I want to check if all the filled in fields are updated but `affected_rows` always returns 0 even when fields are updated.

Is this something to do with the fact that I update with an array of items?

I hope someone could shed some light on this problem.

Comment: Could `_db->prepare` be your problem, changing it to `$db->prepare` might help

Comment: `_db` is actually mysqli connection so. `$db` is something I would use for defining databse class to

Comment: `affected_rows ` is per executed statement. You're executing _different_ statements (bound to different parameters) in a loop and check affected_rows only after. But here `affected_rows` will always be 1 unless you have duplicate `id`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `affected_rows` only applies to the last `execute`. Try this:

```
public function addTranslation( $data = array(), $language ) {
    // Add all words to language
    $stmt = $this->_db->prepare("UPDATE `languages` SET `$language` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $translation, $id);

    $count = 0;
    $affected = 0;
    foreach( $data as $id => $translation ) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $affected += $stmt->affected_rows;

        if( !empty( $translation ) ) {
            $count++;
        }
    }

    // Check if all filled in words are added
    echo $affected;
    if( $affected >= $count ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```